# How to get rid of an apt "Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled" message on upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, paid-applications

When upgrading system with `sudo apt upgrade` I'm getting the following message:

```
(..)
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
(..)
```

I know it's a paid service that can be used by up to 5 hosts/systems for free if it's for personal use, but I don't want to use it. I don't want to get more security updates and in addition, I don't want to see the above message each time I run an upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

There are hacky way to do it

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1452659/69004
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1434762/69004

But if you want to remove all 'pro' services then just uninstall ubuntu advantages package:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

---

In result pro command with its `esm` hook will disappear from you system:

```
$ whereis pro
pro:

$ type /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
-bash: type: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf: not found
```

Comment: Does that remove any other packages?

Comment: Give it a try? You can cancel by pressing `n`

Comment: ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-default-settings : Depends: ubuntu-minimal but it is not going to be installed```

Comment: This will break quite a few packages. At least, as of now. (They may have changed the dependencies since you created the answer.) For me, trying to remove ubuntu-advantage-tools says that ubuntu-minimal and updte-manager-core as well as software-properties-gtk depend on it.

Comment: But actually it's free for personal use on up to 5 machines (and it includes machines own by your own businesses).